# How to make a barplot with ggplot for species richness and diversity in one frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm still a newbie in R, I have some questions and help about using ggplot.

I've been using spadeR for getting species richness and diversity in each sampling location, and I want to make barplot for my data visualization. But I have some trouble getting the right code for ggplot.

This is an example of what I want my data visualization will be.
[image]

But my barplot just look like this

[image]

I want to add a legend on top of the frame, I tried to add it, but it turn out really bad.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this using ggplot, and also for making 2 barplot in one frame like the examples above, how to use parfrow? Hope anyone will teach me how to fix this. Thank you so much!

Here my data set for richness species in 10 sampling locations, includes estimates score of species richness and standard errors.

```
datalw <- as.matrix(data.frame(Bng = c(8, 0.4),
                               Krs= c(3, 0),
                               Bny= c(3, 0),
                               Kmb= c(9.1, 7.40),
                               Sgk= c(3, 0.3),
                               Lwb= c(6.4, 1.0),
                               Lws= c(4.3, 0.7),
                               Krm= c(3, 0.5),
                               Hrt= c(7, 0.5),
                               Gmb= c(6.5, 1.0)))
rownames(datalw) ＜- c("Estimates", "s.e")
datalw                                                  

barplot(datalw,                                         
        col = c("#1b98e0", "#353436"))
legend("top",                                    
       legend = c("estimates", "s.e"),
       fill = c("#1b98e0", "#353436"))
```

Comment: Do you need to use `ggplot`? Or `base R` method will do?

Comment: @DeBARtha yes i need and want to learn to use ggplot for visualization my data :)

Comment: Alright, then it's fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to play around with your data a bit. You didn't have to make `datalw` a matrix because it ends up causing issues. You data also had multiple columns rather than multiple row so I reformatted your data for you.

```
datalw <- structure(list(loc = structure(c(1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 
6L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Bng", "Bny", "Gmb", "Hrt", "Kmb", "Krm", 
"Krs", "Lwb", "Lws", "Sgk"), class = "factor"), V1 = c(8, 3, 
3, 9.1, 3, 6.4, 4.3, 3, 7, 6.5), V2 = c(0.4, 0, 0, 7.4, 0.3, 
1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.5, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Since you want to have your bars side by side you can melt that data together to plot your data easier

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
library(reshape2)

datalw2 <- melt(datalw, id.vars='loc')
```

There is a way to make patterns with `ggplot` you can use `ggpattern`

```
ggplot(datalw2,aes(x=loc, y=value, fill=variable, group=variable, pattern = variable)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(V1 = "stripe", V2 = "crosshatch"))
```

This will produce a plot like this. There are more advanced ways to change the pattern like you have in your picture, however, you will have to create the pattern yourself rather than using default patterns from `ggpattern`

[image: example1]

Your data doesn't have enough information to create the error bars shown in your picture

You can also make the plot black and white like so

```
ggplot(datalw2,aes(x=loc, y=value, fill=variable, group=variable, pattern = variable)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(V1 = "stripe", V2 = "crosshatch")) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = 0)
```

[image: example]

There is a way to create a side by side plot like in your picture however you also don't have enough data to make a second plot

If you want to add the error bars to your graph. You can use `geom_errorbar`. Using the data you provided in your comment below

```
datadv <- structure(list(caves = structure(c(1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 9L,  6L, 4L, 3L),  .Label = c("Bng", "Bny", "Gmb", "Hrt", "Kmb", "Krm", "Krs", "Lwb", "Lws", "Sgk"), class = "factor"), Index = c(1.748, 0.022, 1.066, 1.213, 0.894, 0.863, 1.411, 0.179, 1.611, 1.045),  Std = c(0.078, 0.05, 0.053, 0.062, 0.120, 0.109, 0.143, 0.072, 0.152, 0.171)),  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))

library(ggpattern)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(datadv,aes(x=caves, y=Index)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(V1 = "stripe", V2 = "crosshatch")) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = 0) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Index-Std, ymax=Index+Std), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image: example3]

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer, this really helps me a lot. 
I still have a question, I couldn't install ggpattern in my R. My R is 4.1.1 version. What can I do about this? 
Also, what information for adding an error bar on barplot? I think it used a score for standard errors in each of sampling locations. 

For diversity data, I just tried to make as your answer above. 
My problem right now are about ggpattern

Comment: `datadv <- structure(list(caves = structure(c(1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 9L,  6L, 4L, 3L),  .Label = c("Bng", "Bny", "Gmb", "Hrt", "Kmb", "Krm", "Krs", "Lwb", "Lws", "Sgk"), class = "factor"), Index = c(1.748, 0.022, 1.066, 1.213, 0.894, 0.863, 1.411, 0.179, 1.611, 1.045),  Std = c(0.078, 0.05, 0.053, 0.062, 0.120, 0.109, 0.143, 0.072, 0.152, 0.171)),  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))`

This is my diversity data.

Comment: @SufrahaIslamia Do download ggpattern you have to download it from github. I am not sure why it isn't available elsewhere. `install.packages("remotes")` `remotes::install_github("trevorld/gridpattern")` `remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")` Let me know if one of those work

Comment: I install ggpattern by accessing this remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")

And then i tried to use your code above and it turn out like this:
Error in if (pat == "regular_polygon" && is.numeric(params$pattern_shape)) params$pattern_shape <- "convex6" : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

What should i do?

Comment: I am not really sure why that happened. Did `ggpattern` download without any errors? Do any errors appear when you load the package (`library(ggpattern)`)

Comment: I added how to add the error bars to my answer

Comment: @SufrahaIslamia are you using `datalw2 <- melt(datalw, id.vars='loc')`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that code. I had been checking on the console while installing ggpattern but there is no error appearing when I load the package. 
It just appears like this: Loading required namespace: memoise

Anyway, I tried your codes about the error bar, and it turn out really well. I do on my richness dataset too, and it's perfect. 
but still can't make on your first codes above. idk why :(